# For how long does Mobile Safari remember I allowed it to use my geolocation?

Tags: html, geolocation, mobile-safari

Say a user chooses to allow the usage of geolocation on **Mobile Safari**.

For how long will Mobile Safari remember this decision?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be its by session, every time you refresh the page, Safari Mobile will ask you to allow the website use your coordinates.

Unfortunately I can tell you I'm sure 100% of it because I found nothing according it on the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/index.action).

But according the W3C [documentation](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#scope) you've no time limit. So you can ask one time and keep it as long you want.